# Calculate difference across columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns

I have this `data.frame`:

```
 df <- data.frame(name = c('sample1', 'sample2'),
      a = c(1.12, 3.18),
      b = c(2.23, 6.29),
      c = c(3.62, 1.72),
      d = c(11.56, 6.22),
      e = c(4.11, 19.38))
```

I can calculate the means across columns using:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df_mean <- df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

But how can I get a similar `df` with the difference instead of the mean? I tried this, but it doesn’t work:

```
 df_difference <- df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~.y-.x))
```

Expected result is:

```
 df_difference <- data.frame(a=2.06, b=4.06, b=-1.9, c=-5.34, d=15.27)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~diff(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`. If there are more than two values you might want something different: `range()` or `min()`/`max()`. If you like to stay with your approach, then change to `df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ first(.x) - last(.x)))`. If you want positive differences only, wrap in `abs()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `diff`

```
> df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), diff))
     a    b    c     d     e
1 2.06 4.06 -1.9 -5.34 15.27
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution reference @Friede's comment.

```
df <- df %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~.[-1] - .[1])) 

  a     b     c     d      e
1  2.06  4.06 -1.90 -5.34 15.27
```

The idea is to basically substract 1st row from 2nd. [-1] represents the second row, and [1] represents the first row in each column

Answer (score 2):

**data.table**

```
COLS <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, diff), .SDcols = COLS]
```

**tidyverse**

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c('sample1', 'sample2'),
                 a = c(1.12, 3.18),
                 b = c(2.23, 6.29),
                 c = c(3.62, 1.72),
                 d = c(11.56, 6.22),
                 e = c(4.11, 19.38))

library(purrr)
map_dfc(df[-1], diff)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>       a     b     c     d     e
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2.06  4.06  -1.9 -5.34  15.3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>